# block quote tags differently in content

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress website utilizing Bootstrap 3 framework

functions.php

```
function split_content() {
    global $more;
    $more = true;
    $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
    // first content section in column1
    $ret = '<div id="column1" class="col-md-6"><p>'. array_shift($content). '</p></div>';
    // remaining content sections in column2
    if (!empty($content)) $ret .= '<div id="column2" class="col-md-6"><p>'. implode($content). '</p></div>';
    return apply_filters('the_content', $ret);
}
```

It splits the content after the 'more tag' and puts it in 2 seperate columns.

However when I add a block quote to the beginning of each column (one paragraph in each column with a block quote above each) the second column block quote works fine, but not the first.

picture of the output (blockquotes different for each column)

[image]